# Парсер без вебдрайвера - как можно обойти проверку браузера?

Tags: python, парсер, asyncio, aiohttp

Пытаюсь парсить Avito без использования Selenium.

После нескольких удачно спарсеных страниц, Avito при GET запросе отдаёт мне страницу с загрузкой (проверкa браузера).

Kак можно обойти, не используя вебдрайвер?

Прокси и `asyncio.sleep` пробовал, не помогает.

Вот код:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0'}


def set_proxies():
    file = open('Proxy.txt', 'r')
    proxies_file = file.read().splitlines()
    proxies_list = []
    for each in proxies_file:
        proxies_list.append('http://' + str(each))
    return proxies_list


def get_item(html):
    products = []
    soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
    items = soup.find_all('div', {'itemtype': 'http://schema.org/Product'})
    for item in items:
        title = item.find('a', class_='snippet-link')['title']
        price = item.find('span', {'data-marker': 'item-price'}).text
        link = 'https://www.avito.ru' + item.find('a', class_='snippet-link')['href']
        products.append((title, price.strip(), link))
    return products


async def gen_urls(number):
    root_url = 'https://www.avito.ru/chelyabinsk/tovary_dlya_detey_i_igrushki/kupit-velosipedy_i_samokaty-ASgBAgICAUT~AaCGAQ?q=%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82&p=2'
    for i in range(number):
        num_page = root_url[:-1] + str(i)
        yield num_page


async def request(session, url, proxy):
    async with session.get(url, proxy=proxy, headers=headers) as response:
        return await response.text()


async def crawl(proxy, client, pool):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    proxies = await proxy
    for prox in proxies:
        try:
            for request_future in asyncio.as_completed([request(client, url, prox) async for url in gen_urls(10)]):
                result = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, get_item, await request_future)
                print(result)
        except:
            continue


async def main(proxies):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
            proxy_future = loop.create_future()
            proxy_future.set_result(proxies)
            await crawl(proxy_future, client, pool)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main(set_proxies()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Парсеры палятся на том, что ведут себя как роботы. Люди не обходят все доступные ссылки, только некоторое подмножество без ухода на большую глубину. Чтобы не попасться, надо изобразить группу людей шарящихся по сайту. Для этого надо после разбора страницы входа парсить только две-три ссылки с неё, делать случайные паузы между запросами, потом сбрасывать принятые куки, менять user agent и прокси и парсить другие две-три ссылки. Естественно, прокси не должны быть публичными. Если вы могли найти и скачать их список, то разработчики защиты тоже уже его скачали.