# при парсинге beru.ru отвечает ошибками : '403' либо 'Connection aborted'

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

При попытке парсить сайт beru.ru выдаются ошибки:

403:

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

URL = 'https://m.beru.ru/catalog/tovary-dlia-avto-i-mototekhniki/76688/list?hid=90402&how=aprice#1-0'

class ParserBeru:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.session.headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept-Language': 'ru',
        }

    def get_page(self):
        res = self.session.get(url=self.url)
        res.raise_for_status()
        return res.text

def main():
    Parser = ParserBeru(url=URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(Parser.get_page(), 'lxml')
    print(soup)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Ошибка чтения страницы. Пожалуйста подождите...\n{e}')
        time.sleep(5)
```

и "('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))" при смене headers на:

```html
self.session.headers = {
            'Host':'https://m.beru.ru/',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.5',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'DNT': '1',
            'Connection':'keep-alive',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
            'Pragma': 'no-cache',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
}
```

PS: если парсить с помошью selenium, то все нормально работает. я предполагаю, либо с куками проблема, либо то, что beru отправляет запрос, ну а естественно request на него не отвечает. если напишете пару строчек кода с решением данной проблемы, буду очень признателен :). если почитать ответ, то пишет: "Доступ к нашему сервису временно запрещён!

Возможно, ваш компьютер заражён вредоносной программой, которая автоматически обращается к Яндексу."  и т.д.

**Заренее спасибо за помощь**

Comment: Видимо, для вас будет сюрпризом, что большинство сайтов не любят парсинг и защищаются от него.

Comment: Ахах, походу, ваша программа и есть та самая из разряда вредоносных, которая автоматически обращается к Яндексу. Яндекс вас от нее спас:)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да это понятно, только вопрос, как это сделать...

Comment: @Andruxa_Xren готовых решений и даже рекомендаций вы не найдёте. Придётся победить разработчиков защиты в интеллектуальной дуэли - проанализировать защиту, найти в ней недочёты и [разработать пути обхода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1102534/204271).

Answer (score 2):

Возможно я ошибаюсь, но возможно вам стоит отправлять на сайт куки. Например,

```
HEADERS ={'cookes'= 'erhfuiwhgfiuwerhiw4ueghfwoqghuyq4go7w4gfuier(что-то)'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
```

Надеюсь помог